# TFS 2008 Sourcecode security

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2008 for Web App dev. The WebApp is a large project, so we do not want every developer to see all the source code, which means lots of libraries or subapps need to be referenced.If I put all the libraries and subapps in one VS2008 Project or VS2008 Team Project, all the source codes will be exposed to each person.

Do I have to make the WebApp reference other Team Project to solve this problem? What is the best way doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider each isolated section to be a project (in both the physical and management sense) as independent.  Ship release from those shared components/projects and deliver them as binaries to be pulled into the others.  You can use a the output from trunk or release branch builds of the shared components to deliver new "releases".

This affords you the option of full branching, work item, reporting etc for each logical project in your organization.

Answer (score 0):

If you let someone be a contributor/developer on a project, then that individual has access to the entire project. If you want to keep someone out of the certain files, then that will need to be under its own TFS project. You would then reference the output assemblies from the parent project in the child project.